# VBA : how to set option on webpage, as it will change the page's content

Tags: html, vba, excel

I was trying to copy monthly performance data from investing.com

When I type "http://www.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-historical-data" for the website, it presents, at default value, only daily data.

However, I want to catch monthly performance. On the website, I can simply click drop down menu and click "monthly".

I find the webpage code (maybe called xml?) for the drop down menu:

```
 <div class="float_lang_base_1">
         <select class="newInput selectBox float_lang_base_1" id="data_interval">
             <option value="Daily" selected="">Daily</option>
             <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
             <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
         </select>
     </div>
```

I have tried to change the "selected" attribute to monthly, by such vba code:

```
html.getElementsByTagName("select")("data_interval").Children(0).removeAttribute("selected", "=") = ""
html.getElementsByTagName("select")("data_interval").Children(2).setAttribute("selected", "") = ""
```

The page will present "monthly" in the time frame drop down menu, but it did not work out. The data I download will still be daily.

I have also tried to change the value of "time frame" to "Monthly", I got the same result. The code is as follows:

```
html.getElementsByTagName("select")("data_interval").Value = "Monthly"
```

Both present the webpage like this: [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ie65.png)

Is there any method to solve the problem?

There is also code in the webpage.

```
function historical_submit(isInterval) {
    var isDatePicked = !isInterval;
    if(!firstTimePicker) isDatePicked=true;
    var dateFormat = $.datepicker.regional[''].dateFormat;
    var dateTo =new Date();
    var dateFrom = new Date();
    var intervalInDays=30;
    if(isDatePicked) {
        var dates = $.datepicker._getFromToDates($.datepicker._curInst,'yy-mm-dd');
        if (dates !== null) {
            dateFrom=dates.dateFrom;
            dateTo=dates.dateTo;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($('#data_interval').val() === 'Weekly') {intervalInDays = 52 * 7}; //365 - full year
        if ($('#data_interval').val() === 'Monthly') {intervalInDays = 30 * 24}; //~ 2 years
        var dateFromObj=new Date();
        dateFromObj.setDate(dateFromObj.getDate() - intervalInDays);
        dateFrom= dateFromObj;//$.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat,dateFromObj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
html.getElementById("data_interval").options.selectedIndex = 2;
```

**REVISION**

After further investigation, the onchange event must be triggered. Let's try this:

```
var selected = html.getElementById("data_interval");
selected.options.selectedIndex = 2;
selected.onchange();
```

**REVISION-2**

```
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Set thtml = html.createDocumentFromUrl("http://bunkerhill.com/test.html", vbNull)
Dim sel As HTMLSelectElement
sel = html.getElementsByClassName("newInput selectBox")
sel.selectedIndex = 2
sel.FireEvent ("afterupdate")
```

[Pure JavaScript jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j12ebL3u/1/)

Comment: it does not... and there is a error: "object doesn't support this property or method"                                                                                                                I tried ".selectedIndex", as I think you might get a typo. But got the same result, "Monthly" on "time frame", with the daily data presented on the webpage and in my excel

Comment: It was a typo. So, even though the drop-down box shows Monthly, you  are sill getting daily data? Can you post your download code?

Comment: I modified your code, by "Var" to "Set", and `.onchange()` to `onchange`, but there is a error: "application-defined or object-defined error". ___  I later switched `.onchange` to `.FireEvent("onchange")` (in fact i dont know what it means, but just copy it somewhere in stackoverflow). it goes to "Monthly", but no data changed.

Comment: I get code in the webpage, maybe JavaScript basis. I can understand it, but I do not know what I can do with it.

Comment: I am sorry, I omit your question. And yes, it shows Monthly, but I get daily data, in all of these methods.

Comment: I am not sure why you needed to modify the code. It is pure JavaScript. Did you view the jsfiddle? What browser and version are you using? I have tested with Chrome and IE 10. I think the VBA browser control uses IE.  With IE I needed to wrap the code in an window.onload = function() {...} event.

Comment: In VBA I use IE. I modify it because in VBA, it says "compile error: sub or function not defined" if I do not change `var` to `set`, and "compile error: expect =" if I do not dismiss the parenthesis. I tried `Selected.onchange() = True`, but got the same result. I guess you had got a wrong link when you edit the pure java, but I ahve finally opened it...I will learn carefully to see if I can wield it on my vBA code.

Comment: Does your version of Excel include a Browser control like VB.NET? Is the Var (capitalized) a typo? It should be lower case "var".

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have added "Microsoft html object library" and "Microsoft Internet Controls" in reference. I tried DEVELOPER>Insert>More Controls>Microsoft Web Browser, but it says "cannot insert object". No, `var` or `Var` are not typo. I type `var` in vba and it automatically turns into `Var`. ... I am not sure if there is a method could work... maybe I will try to access the function that embedded in the webpage, and apply the function?

Comment: There is no "var" in VBA, the equivalent is "Dim".  I was able to load the references you mentioned, so now we can be on the same page. Can you show me your VBA code?

Comment: Sure. Can I send you a email or something? or i'll edit on my question?

Comment: Hold on a moment. I am testing some VBA code using the HTML Object library. I think I am almost there.

Comment: See REVISION-2. I am getting an error on 'sel = html.getElementsByClassName("newInput selectBox")' but am hoping you can fix it.

Comment: I guess maybe you should try "newInput selectBox float_lang_base_1". I ran the REVISION-2 and there is variable that not set? But I cannot tell which one...

Comment: In fact, I found that if I can update dates on the up right of the chart from http://www.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-historical-data, I can update the whole data if the up left drop down menu shows "Monthly". Maybe I should try my best on adjust the dates changing.

Comment: Hi Ron, I would like to say thank you for what you have done... Although the problem still remains, but it took you whole day helping me to solve this. Many thanks. @ron tornambe